# How to obtain the cellEditorSelector values

Tags: ag-grid

I need to show a list of values that I get from a request to an api. In the documentation the example is this

```
if (params.data.type === 'gender') return {
            component: 'agRichSelectCellEditor',
            params: {values: ['Male', 'Female']}
        };
```

Can I substitute ['Male','Female'] for any variable that has the result of the api?
Can I call to my own function where I call to api?
Regards

Answer (score 1):

```
cellEditor: "agRichSelectCellEditor",
cellEditorParams: { values: this.getSuppliers() }.
```

Solved